# What is the use of value_type in STL containers?

Tags: c++, stl

What's the use of `value_type` in STL containers?

From the MSDN:

```
// vector_value_type.cpp
// compile with: /EHsc
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

int main( )
{
   using namespace std;
   vector<int>::value_type AnInt;
   AnInt = 44;
   cout << AnInt << endl;
}
```

I don't understand what does `value_type` achieve here?
The variable could be an `int` as well? Is it used because the coders are lazy to check what's the type of objects present in the vector?

I think these are also similar to it `allocator_type`,`size_type`,`difference_type`,`reference`,`key_type` etc..

Comment: Consider C++03. What is the correct element type for a `std::vector<T>`?

Comment: This doesn't respond to the question, but do you really need all the stuff that `std::endl` does? `'\n'` ends a line.

Answer (score 47, accepted):

Yes, in your example, it is pretty easy to know that you need an `int`.  Where it gets complicated is generic programming.  For example, if I wanted to write a generic `sum()` function, I would need it to know what kind of container to iterate and what type its elements are, so I would need to have something like this:

```
template<typename Container>
typename Container::value_type sum(const Container& cont)
{
    typename Container::value_type total = 0;
    for (const auto& e : cont)
        total += e;
    return total;
}
```

Comment: what is the difference between this and just returning Container in the function declaration?

Comment: @bigbrownbear00 you wouldn't want to return the whole container when you want a sum of all of its elements.  You just want an object of the type the container holds.

Comment: If you want to support multiple containers then I see why you would do this. But if you sent a vector you could just return template type.

Comment: @BigBrownBear00 The whole point of writing generic code is to be as generic as possible.  Sure I could have use `template<typename T> T sum(const std::vector<T>& cont)` but that limits the code.  The version I used in my function will support any container that can be used in a range based for loop which makes it a lot more versatile.

Comment: This also has the benefit for making the code future proof as latter on if you change the type of the object you are passing to `sum` you don't have to change the function call.

Comment: Why we can't just use smth like this: typename Container::T, why we need to use typedef?

Comment: @Anapheron Because `T` is not something you can access from outside the class.  They would have to add an alias to the class like `using T = _Ty;` which is what they do for `value_type`.