# Why alias a template parameter in C++ standard containers?

Tags: c++, class, templates, std, type-alias

Reviewing the code of Microsoft's STL (specifically `std::vector`), I came across the following lines of code (irrelevant code replaced with `/* ... */`):

```cpp
// CLASS TEMPLATE vector
template <class _Ty, class _Alloc = allocator<_Ty>>
class vector // varying size array of values
{ 
    /* ... */
public:

   /* ... */
   using value_type = _Ty;
   using allocator_type = _Alloc;
   using pointer = typename _Alty_traits::pointer;
   using const_pointer = typename _Alty_traits::const_pointer;
   using reference = _Ty&;
   using const_reference = const _Ty&;
   using size_type = typename _Alty_traits::size_type;
   using difference_type = typename _Alty_traits::difference_type;
   /* ... */
};
```

I was wondering why the convention of assigning a type alias to a template type is used here?

Comment: "I was wondering why the convention of assigning a type alias to a template type is used here?" - For a definitive answer you'd need to ask the Microsoft people who wrote that code. But, *my* *guess* would be that it's done to make the code more readable. Also, some of those names are specified by the standard, so they have to provide them, but for the template types they have to use reserved names like `_Foo`.

Comment: Seems to be duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44571362/what-is-the-use-of-value-type-in-stl-containers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I was wondering why the convention of assigning a type alias to a
> template type is used here?

Because it is

- the standard way of doing,
- makes less error-prone code,
- less typing,
- more readable, and
- all the above makes life easy!

For instance, let's consider the [`const_pointer`, public template alias of `std::vector`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector#Member_types)

```
using const_pointer   = typename _Alty_traits::const_pointer;
```

At some point, you want to know this type and use in a function, how could have been possible without the above alias?

Of course, you [can write](https://godbolt.org/z/var1GK)

```
#include <memory> // std::allocator_traits

using const_pointer = typename std::allocator_traits<typename std::vector</*type*/>::allocator_type>::const_pointer;
```

anywhere in your program. But that tends to **more error-prone** situations (e.g. missing some `typename`s and so on), and **more typing**.

Therefore, it makes sense to collect those kinds of types of a container and provide public-aliases-types.

Answer (score 5):

> I was wondering why the convention of assigning a type alias to a template type is used here?

Suppose you have a template function that accept an STL container (`std::vector`, `std::deque`, `std::set`, `std::multi_set`, ...)

```
template <typename T>
void foo (T const & t)
 {
   // ...
 }
```

and that you need the type of contained values.

You can, inside `foo()`, simply write

```
 using needed_type = typename T::value_type;
```

and this works for `std::vector`, `std::deque`, `std::set`, `std::multi_set`, `std::array`, `std::map`, `std::multi_map`, etc.

Comment: So they essentially are standardizing a way to access the template parameter types outside the class definition itself?

Answer (score 2):

The C++ standard requires `std::vector` to provide a double-handful of nested names, and those are the ones the question is asking about. That's why `value_type`, `allocator_type`, `pointer`, etc. are there. You can use those names in your code when you need the types that they refer to. It's not at all uncommon to see, for example, `std::vector<int>::iterator` in user code to refer to the type of the iterator that `std::vector<int>` provides.

As to why they're written the way they are, that's a broader consistency issue. Templates throughout the Dinkumware implementation of the C++ standard library (which is what Microsoft ships) use `_Ty` as the base name for general types. When there are two types you'll see `_Ty1` and `_Ty2`. When there's an internal typedef for a name it will be `_Myty` (for "My" type). That consistency makes maintaining the code easier.

Answer (score 1):

That convention actually used for providing "traits". Naming for those types follows some convention that allows write functions like [`distance`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/distance) in terms of those traits and make it working for many containers.

And I'm pretty sure that having those types for standard C++ library is part of specification and they had to adhere it.