# What "using value_type = T;" does in a c++ template?

Tags: c++, templates, type-alias

In the following code:

```
template<typename T, int N>
struct Buffer {
    using value_type = T;
    constexpr int size() { return N; }
    T[N];
};
```

can you explain to me what this line does and what happens if we remove it?

```
using value_type = T;
```

Comment: Are your more familiar with (old) `typedef`?

Comment: TL;DR of the dupe: `using value_type = T;` creates an alias for `T` called `value_type`

Comment: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/type_alias

Comment: It will basically make `Buffer::value_type` equivalent to `Buffer::T`

Comment: @CoryKramer: there is no `Buffer::T`, precisely...

Comment: If you remove it, it will be difficult to get to the Buffer template's T parameter.  By providing the `using`, it makes generic programming and template meta programming much easier.

Comment: And if your next question is why have a `value_type`, see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44571362/what-is-the-use-of-value-type-in-stl-containers/44571482#44571482

Comment: @NathanOliver If I have T why would I want to rename it value_type? is value_type[N]; work here?

Comment: @Fractale You have `T` inside the class, but people outside the class don't.  They can't do `Buffer::T` to get the template type.

Comment: @NathanOliver Each vector with a different T will make a different value_type right? Is value_type a field? Is it useful only for template that uses Buffer and wants to know T? Can value_type be used somewhere else than another template?

Comment: `value_type` is a type alias.  It doesn't take up any space.  For each `Buffer<T>`, you will have a `value_type` for each different `T` you use.  `value_type` can be used outside template code, but template code is the most common use as that is where it's needed the most.  When you aren't in a template, you should know what type of `Buffer` you have, so `value_type` isn't so useful.  In template code, you might not even know what type of container you have, but if all containers have a `value_type` member, then you at least have a way to get the type of the elements in the container.

Comment: You might have a situation like `std::string`, which is an alias for `std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char>>`. You could find `std::string::value_type` in non-template code that uses strings

Comment: @NathanOliver in a template you will use O::value_type as a type to declare a variable because you don't have any information on O<T>. if this function took a Buffer<T, N> as a parameter you can just use T as normal. So value_type is useful when you want to generalize more and leave the Buffer type outside the template definition. Is it correct?

Comment: @Fractale Correct.  Imagine you have `template <typename Container> something sum(const Container& cont)`.  Here you only know you have a container, so `something` needs to be replaced with `typename Container::value_type` and inside the function, the variable you do your accumulation needs to be declared like `typename Continer::value_type accumulator{};`

Comment: @NathanOliver concerning the non-template code, How do I access the value? And How to use it? Is it useful for something? Is it something similar to the following code? Buffer<int,100> b; if(b::value_type == int) {cout<<"I have a vector of int!"}

Comment: @Fractale Like I said, there is no real point to it outside of template code.  If you have a `Buffer<int, 10>`, then you already know everything you need to know about it.

Comment: @NathanOliver Thank you for your really clear and eye-opening explanations.